# Focus On Listview last added Item

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps

I am working on windows store app, where I am using `ListView` control to add data dynamically. The items are added at the end of the list. The `Scrollbar` appears when more data is added. I want to highlight last added item programatically with scroll bar at the bottom. I don't want to scroll the scroll bar manually to see last added item. How can I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
        listView1.EnsureVisible(listView1.Items.Count - 1);
```

Comment: EnsureVisible function is not in Windows 8 development toolkit.

Comment: so u are using the XAML listview right? I can't test it but u can try the '[ScrollIntoView(object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br242911.aspx)'

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
yourListView.ScrollIntoView(yourListView.Items[yourListView.Items.Count - 1]);
```